# How To Parsing JSON from URL into HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html, json

Here's the code as I'm writing it. It looks correct, but won't parse from the url given. ([This Link](https://api.samsara.com/v1/fleet/assets/locations?access_token=MrK3UCw9vu2a5HlCa2n6dOogyYtPcX)) I'm only trying to parse the "Location" and "Name" variable. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>

    <script>

        $(function() {


       var assets = [];

       $.getJSON('https://api.samsara.com/v1/fleet/assets/locations?access_token=MrK3UCw9vu2a5HlCa2n6dOogyYtPcX', function(data) {
           $.each(data.assets, function(i, f) {
              var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.location + "</td>" +
               "<td>" + f.name + "</td>" + "</tr>"
               $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
         });

       });

    });
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="profile">
       <table id= "userdata">
      <thead>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th>Name</th>

            </thead>
          <tbody>

           </tbody>
       </table>

    </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You should change your access token.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: What do you mean it won't parse from the URL? Are you getting the data back?

Comment: Does `f` reflect the URL passed to `$.getJSON()`, or different data? What does `console.log(f)` print? Or, are you trying to parse the URL passed to `$.getJSON()` before the request is made?

Comment: What does your developer console say, is it receiving the correct ajax response?

Comment: Im trying to parse the info from the link into an html table, and the code only gives the header for the table and not the data

Comment: @Z.Ours That's not enough info for us to help you. It appears you haven't debugged this enough. Use your browser's Developer Tools to watch what is happening. You can see your AJAX request and your data through that. An easy way to do it first time: write `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` just above the `$.each...` line, and then run your code. Open the Developer Tools for your page and look in your Console tab. What does it say? Can you see your JSON data? Or any errors? Please tell us what it says.